# Using Maven Surefire, how can I parallelize parameterized jUnit tests?

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

I am using jUnit's Parameterized annotation on some Selenium tests to specify the browsers they should run with. I am also using SureFire's new parallel parameter (set to "classes") to try and run them in parallel. Am I correct in assuming that if I have X test classes and Y browsers, I should see X*Y windows pop up, X of each type? I'm only seeing Y windows pop up at a time.

For example, let's say I have my parameter list set to Firefox and Chrome, and I have 10 test classes. When I execute the tests with Maven, I'm seeing one Firefox window and one Chrome window appear on my remote server at a time. I want to see 10 of each, one for each class, so it takes less time to run. Is this possible?

Comment: For future visitors, this question was re-posted and answered at "Software Quality Assurance and Testing": https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/how-can-i-use-surefire-to-run-parameterized-tests-in-parallel